# Send socket message delay in mitmproxy addon

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I want to customize a addon to filter the specified HOST request, and can send some socket messages unidirectionally after each successful filtering, but every time receiving a socket message in another process will generate a delay of about 0.15s.
Is there a better way please, or where is the problem with my code?

System Information:

- Mitmproxy: 6.0.2
- List item
- Python: 3.8.0
- Platform: macOS-12.2.1
  The main code of the addon:

```
class MyAddon:
    @script.concurrent
    def request(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow):
       ...

    @script.concurrent
    def response(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow):
        msg = ... #Create a message
        if flow.request.host in HOST_LIST:
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
                s.connect((HOST, PORT))
                s.send(msg)
```

This is the server process code:

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        port = 9999
        self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
        self.sock.listen(10)
        self.sever_th = threading.Thread(target=self.tcp_server)
        self.sever_th.start()

    def tcp_server(self):
        while True:
            t0 = time.time()
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept() #There is a delay of about 0.15s
            print('%0.5f' % (time.time() - t0))
            with conn:
                buff = b''
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                    if data == b'':
                        print(buff)
                        break
                    else:
                        buff += data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
```

I have tried sending messages using one socket, but the delay effect is still the same.
I use the Socket to send multiple groups of the same message without the Addon, and there is no such high delay.The bytes of each message sent are about 600 Bytes.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. If you want to add more information please do not use comments without someone to discuss, edit your question instead. If timing is a problem why don't you make the socket connection in a  separate thread. Multi-threading is not perfectly on Python but at least it is present and could be used to not adding an additional delay.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your prompt,I want to make use of the data generated by Multi-threading to combine the message and send it through the socket.